# Azure SQL POOL Elasticity

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Just wanted to be sure if this is possible:

I am having all my app services in separate subscription, I want to use Sql pool elasticity for which I will create a separate subscription in which only my DBs will reside and will add all my DBs to this pool which I will create on this subscription.

**Problems:**
    1.Is it possible for my apps in different subscription to access the DB in another subscription?
    2. If the above scenario is possible then will it hamper performance of my apps?
    3. Will I be charged Data Transfer Cost for this? What if the region of the app and Db is same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> 1.Is it possible for my apps in different subscription to access the DB in another subscription?

Yes.  The Firewall and Authentication are not related to the subscription at all.

> 2. If the above scenario is possible then will it hamper performance of my apps?

No.

> 3. Will I be charged Data Transfer Cost for this? What if the region of the app and Db is same?

There is no data egress charge between resources in the same region.